# Почему получаю чушь вместо кода страницы? requests python

Tags: python, requests

Здрасте всем.

Пытаюсь получить код страницы, но в итоге получаю что-то вроде этого, только много

"ԭ����0�����9a�i��{�����+�4�N�`�Ya"

через сайт https://a.pr-cy.ru/ посмотрел кодивроку. utf-8...

```
import requests

def get_data(url):
    headers = {
        'ляляля': 'тратата' #в общем хедерс тут
    }

    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    with open('index.html', 'w') as file:
        file.write(r.text)

def main():
    get_data('https://tury.ru/hotel/most_luxe.php')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

в итоге в html файле белиберда.

версия питона 3.11

памагити.

Comment: Это весь код? Вы функцию хоть вызываете? У меня нормально сохраняет html, даже без headers. Если функцию вызвать, конечно.

Comment: with open('index.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:

Comment: @СергейКох не помогло

Comment: Пробуйте python 3.10, возможно в 3.11 еще какие-то баги есть.

Comment: А где именно вы кракозябры видите?

Comment: У меня на Linux на python 3.11 (Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 19:56:13) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux) нормально работает. Может вы не тот файл смотрите? Попробуйте просто `print(r.text[:100])` сделать.

Comment: заявленая кодировка может отличатся от фактической, и как я вангую тут гдето есть кои8, да и бом сигнатура

Comment: @ganz, это вообще не похоже ни на какую кодировку, это скорее мусор или бинарные данные. Плюс там html код, его было бы видно в любой кодировке плюс-минус читаемо.

Comment: @insolor ставлю  на кодировку плюс первый символ похож на бом сигнатуру,

Comment: дело было вот в чём. у меня в хедерсе в 'accept-encoding': было 'br'. не знаю на что это влияет, но ребята подсказали, и без 'br' всё заработало